# Filtering and Delay Compensation in Matlab and Simulink

Tags: matlab, pll, simulink, fsk

I have built a FSK modulator and demodulator in Simulink.

Everything is working fine except the received signal after the channel has short spikes, which are introducing a short pulses in the regenerator output.

The plot for the graph after the demodulation and regeneration,

[image]

My demodulator design is:

[image]

My regenerator design is:

[image]

AIM: I would like to remove those spikes. Those spikes are introducing delay. Which can be confirmed by comparing them with my input bit stream.

Input bit stream: 
[image]

The PLL filter parameters are: [image]

I am a beginner in Simulink and I would like to know the ideas that you guys would employ in this situation. I would welcome both Matlab and Simulink solutions.

But as my implementation involves Simulink, it would be great if one guides me in Simulink.

Here is the complete plot of all the blocks output: 
1. Input bits
2. Modulator output
3. Channel output
4. Demodulator output
5. regenerator output

[image]

I am using the carrier frequencies of 2*pi*8 rad/sec and 2*pi*12 rad/sec.

Comment: perhaps the problem is in the modulator?  Are you using Double-precision floating point in demod?

Comment: Does Mod spectrum look like this? http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/commblks/getstarted/fskspect.gif

Comment: Something is very strange about your data. Your filter output is swinging between positive voltages and negative voltages, with virtually no "open space" between them. Also, the VCO settings are for 10 Hz/V with a 10 Hz bias. Exactly what frequencies are you using to carry your data? I suspect that if you adjust the cutoff frequency of your filter to be closer to the bit rate than the carrier frequency, you'll get much better results.

Comment: @TonyStewart...I am not using Double Precision floating point in demodulator.

Comment: @DaveTweed...I have updated my question with plots of the module at all the blocks and also the carrier frequencies I am using, please check.

Comment: Have you tried making the change to the filter that I suggested? If this were working correctly, we'd see the filter output swinging between +0.2V (12 Hz) and -0.2V (8 Hz). Instead, we see it decaying to zero on every carrier cycle.

Comment: @DaveTweed   If I keep the Low Pass cut off frequency close to my bit rate, there is a marginal imrovement in the filter output, but not significant. The result after the regeneration remain the same. I have implemented zero crossing detector with gaurd interval in matlab which does the perfect work, but I dont know how to implement that in Simulink, I will explore more on that. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you're doing something fundamentally wrong. I don't know anything about the Simulink PLL specifically, but it would be interesting to see its PD and VCO outputs as well. Zoom in on the time scale so that we can see individual cycles of the input signal, in an area where a glitch occurs.

Comment: @DaveTweed...just to be clear...the PLL works absolutely ok, without the channel.  I started getting these spikes in the filter output, only after I introduced the channel. So I have to do channel delay and distortion compensation, if I have to recover my signal properly. I know zero crossing method suits well here...I am working on it....i wouldn't go for PLL in this case I guess. Thanks.

Comment: So why didn't you mention this up front? And why do you not believe that making the PLL more robust can help you deal with the distortions introduced by the channel?